Есть ли возможность силами PHP получить HTML-код страницы Сообщества вКонтакте?
Пытаюсь получить HTML-код страницы Сообщества вКонтакте следующим образом:
        $url = 'https://vk.com/neshkolabarabanov';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 13; Mobile; rv:120.0) Gecko/120.0 Firefox/120.0');
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

На выходе - пустая строка.

$out = file_get_contents($url);
такой вариант тоже возвращает пустую строку

Curl и CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION тебе в помощь)  а еще советую липовые заголовки поставить как у браузера https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/

@Eugene спасибо за подсказки! Всё заработало!

Добавил CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.
Изменил CURLOPT_USERAGENT.
Заработало:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');


В ответ на этот запрос приходят только заголовки с кодом ответа 302 для перемещения на мобильную версию https://m.vk.com/. Т.к. запрос является перенаправляющим, рассчитанным на браузер, то и нужда в html-странице опускается.
Если интересно, убедиться в этом можно с помощью утилиты командной оболочки curl с параметром -v.

спасибо за помощь и объяснение процесса!
